# How to fetch the number of unacknowledged messages in a Pub/Sub Subscription via the Google Cloud Monitoring JAVA Client Library

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring

I have a number on Pub/Sub subscriptions created which do NOT have a consumer attached and can store messages upto 7 days. This is because ideally the number of messages in these Pub/Sub should not go over a certain threshold. I want to monitor these Pub/Sub periodically from my app and then handle the messages in the rare case that the number goes over the threshold. If not, even setting an alert for the same helps.

I know that I can setup Cloud Monitoring from the Google Cloud Console for the subscriptions and create dashboards/alerts. Is there a way to do this programmatically via the JAVA Client Library (Google Cloud Monitoring [Link to Documentation](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-monitoring/latest/index.html))?. As there aren't a lot of code samples available, I am finding it difficult.

TLDR: How to fetch the number of unack messages in a Pub/Sub Subscription, in my code using the google-cloud-monitoring JAVA client Library

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`listTimeSeries`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-monitoring/latest/com/google/cloud/monitoring/v3/MetricServiceClient.html#listTimeSeries-com.google.monitoring.v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest-) method to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***MetricServiceClient.[ListTimeSeriesRequest](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-cloud-monitoring/latest/com/google/cloud/monitoring/v3/MetricServiceClient.html#listTimeSeries-com.google.monitoring.v3.ListTimeSeriesRequest-)*** to read these metrics programmatically (e.g. *subscription/num_undelivered_messages*). The Cloud Monitoring docs page contains examples of how to initialize the client library in general: https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/reference/libraries#using_the_client_library