# How can I alert on a large increase (numeric, not percent) in a GCP metric?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-monitoring, gcp-alerts

I'm attempting to monitor a dead letter queue for a large increase in failures. Ideally if the count of unacked messages increases by, say, 50 in a 10 minute period, I'd like to know. Something like this:

| Count @ period start | Count @ period end | Alert? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 | No |
| 20 | 26 | No |
| 26 | 90 | Yes |
| 90 | 92 | No |
| 92 | 200 | Yes |

Any 10 minute window there's an increase of >50, I want to know about it. I see lots of summing and counting functions, and a percentage change function, but I'm not sure how to put them together to get the result I want.

Comment: Do [thread1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64056103/) and [thread2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53562350/) help you?

Comment: @kiranmathew unfortunately, they don't. I don't want an alert when it reaches a certain # of messages in the dead queue, I want an alert when the change between two time periods exceeds a certain number.